# Get values from different tables with codeigniter into a single array?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

Say I have two tables in my database: `sites` and `sitetype1`

`sites` has the following columns:

**`Slug`**    **`Name`**    **`Url`**

`slug1`    `Site1`    `site1.com`

`slug2`    `Site2`    `site2.com`

`sitetype1` has the following columns:

**`Slug`**    **`Description`**

`slug1`    `Description for site1`

`slug2`    `Description for site2`

In codeigniter, I ideally need to fetch these values so that they reside in `name` => `slug` pairs.

So I'm trying to get an array that looks something like:

```
['Site1' => 'slug1', 'Site2' => 'slug2']
```

Previously, I'd done it by an extremely inefficient method of fetching the slugs from the `sitetype1` table and then cycling through those and fetching a corresponding `name` value from the `sites` array. This seems like an overly complicated way of going about it. I'm looking at joins to complete the task, but I am very bad with MySQL and require some help.

I've tried this:

```
$this->db->select('name','slug');
$this->db->from('sites');
$this->db->join('sitetype1', 'sitetype1.slug = sites.slug','inner');
```

However it only returns the corresponding `name` values. Could anyone help me out from here on?

This is an example of what it returns:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#22 (1) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "Site1"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#23 (1) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "Site2"
  }
}
```

Comment: You couldnt get `slug` column, right?

Comment: did you try $this->db->select('name,slug'); or $this->db->select('name,sites.slug as newSlug');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use like ;)

```
$this->db->select('sites.name, sitetype1.slug');
```

**Wrong:** `'name','slug'`

**Right:** `'name, slug'`

Comment: You were nearly correct, I have found that this is the correct syntax: `$this->db->select('name, sitetype1.slug');`